# Laravel, two api PUT actions, one works other doesn't

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5, routes, put

I send API PUT request from javascript, in one case it works, in another it doesn't.

```
Request URL: http://project.local/api/contestant
Request Method: PUT
404
```

```
Request URL: http://project.local/api/user
Request Method: PUT
200
```

```
Route::put('contestant', 'ApiContestantController@store');
Route::put('user', 'ApiUserController@store');
```

I checked routes/api.php few times, javascript code is similar, and don't know what should I check next.

EDIT:
This works on another environment. Same code. Similar configuration (db credentials are different) and maybe file permissions.

Comment: I can guess that your `namespace` in the `ApiContestantController` is wrong, hence the route/file could not be found.

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers; In both files. They are in same folder. Copied one from another and only replaces some variable names.

Comment: 404 means not found, so make sure you don't misspell any class name or anything.

Comment: Did you clear your route cache? ```php artisan route:clear```

Comment: Yep - still 404. Also no misspelling.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it's a simple misspell. make sure `ApiContestantController.php` file is in `app/http/controllers` directory and the first line contains `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`, be careful about the capital `A` of `App` and also the class name must be `ApiContestantController` same as the file name (check the file and class name about capital letters, they always bust me).

if you checked all of them and still returns error, check if your csrf token attached in that request. to make sure if it's related to csrf token, temporarily change the method to `get` and return a simple string and log it in console.

inform me of results in comments.